# Kubernetes worker node is in Not Ready state

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, kubeadm

I am comparatively new to kubernetes but i have successfully created many clusters before. Now i am facing an issue where i tried to add a node to an already existing cluster. At first kubeadm join seems to be successful but even after initializing the pod network only the master became into Ready.

`root@master# kubectl get nodes
NAME                       STATUS     ROLES     AGE       VERSION
master-virtual-machine     Ready      master    18h       v1.9.0
testnode-virtual-machine   NotReady   <none>    16h       v1.9.0`

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: More often than not, `kubectl describe testnode-virtual-machine` will show events at the bottom related to *why* that Node is not ready. But, failing that, ssh-ing into the node and looking at the logs on the machine, those from kubelet, plus any containers, may surface more details than you have provided thus far

Comment: Thanks @MatthewLDaniel..
kubectl describe node testnode-virtual-machine says..
runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized.
And kubelet logs says

Comment: W1221 12:29:59.085231   17497 cni.go:171] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d. what to do?

Comment: logs suggest network to be defined in /etc/cni/net.d but i do not see any cni folder under /etc. Also i reverified that i have latest kubelet and kubernetes-cni installed. Also got another error in logs saying  * Starting health server failed: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: bind: address already in use
* kubelet.go:1275] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /
* kubelet.go:1359] No api server defined - no node status update will be sent.
Potential bug?

Comment: Yeah, that was what I suspected; the introduction of CNI has jammed up many a cluster-provisioner. However, when combined with all the other horrible errors you mentioned in your 3rd comment, I would suggest carefully examining your cluster provisioning strategy, because it seems like there is not just one misconfiguration at work here and fixing them all would take some major back-and-forth on S.O.

Answer (score 0):

try the following on the slave node and try to get the status again on master.

```
> sudo swapoff -a

> exit
```

Comment: This is incomplete advice because, while doing so will disable Swap, it will not prevent it from being mounted again on the next boot. OP would need to also remove the Swap partition from their /etc/fstab, systemd-mount, or equivalent file.